# Discrepancy in PowerShell type checking operators between function and console (PS7)?

Tags: powershell, powershell-7.3

I am trying to write a PowerShell function that can take an input object and return whether or not it is a collection.  For my purposes, I do NOT wish to treat a string as a collection even though `"stringLiteral" -is [System.Collections.IEnumerable]` returns `True` in PowerShell, so I wrote my function like so:

```
function IsCollection {
    [CmdletBinding()]
    param (
        [Parameter( Mandatory = $true )]
        [object] $Input
    )

    if ( $Input -is [System.Collections.IEnumerable] -AND $Input -isnot [string] ) {
        return $true
    }
    else {
        return $false
    }
}
```

However, when trying to test this function directly in a fresh PowerShell console session, I am getting what appears to be inconsistent behavior between the function and commands issued directly in the console.  Here is what I am seeing, copied directly from the session:

```
PowerShell 7.3.9
Version: 7.3.9
Loading personal and system profiles took 567ms.

PS C:\Users\ornsio> function IsCollection {
>>     [CmdletBinding()]
>>     param (
>>         [Parameter( Mandatory = $true )]
>>         [object] $Input
>>     )
>>
>>     if ( $Input -is [System.Collections.IEnumerable] -AND $Input -isnot [string] ) {
>>         return $true
>>     }
>>     else {
>>         return $false
>>     }
>> }

PS C:\Users\ornsio> IsCollection "test"
True

PS C:\Users\ornsio> IsCollection 23
True

PS C:\Users\ornsio> $lump = [object]::new()

PS C:\Users\ornsio> IsCollection $lump
True

PS C:\Users\ornsio> $lump -is [System.Collections.IEnumerable]
False

PS C:\Users\ornsio> $lump -is [string]
False
```

Why does the function always return `True`?

My first thought was that maybe it is treating the `$Input` argument as a true `[object]` type without being able to "see" its runtime type (which wouldn't really make a lot of sense), but as you can see above, when creating an `[object]` type variable directly in the console and then running the type checks against it, the results still don't match up.

I have tried Googling this, but this is a hard one to make a search engine "understand", and I have not had any luck.

Comment: `IEnumerable` is the wrong interface to understand if an object is a collection, you should use `ICollection` instead or `IList` (depending on if you want to include / exclude dictionary types)

Comment: My first thought was also that this is at best going to test if an object implements IEnumerable (and is not a string).

Comment: Is it possible your command line arguments are always coming in as a list of some kind (sort of like what you would imagine `args[]` would be ... if that makes sense)

Comment: What would be the purpose of your `IsCollection` function? What real-life tasks/problems are you trying to solve with it? Are you trying to determine whether an object is going to be enumerate if you pipe it?

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen, I am writing this function for use in other functions to allow them to provide flexible input arguments that can be treated differently based on whether or not they represent a single value or an enumerable collection of values.  While not a function, an analgous example of the type of function I'm talking about would be the way that the -match operator returns True or False when passed a single string, and instead returns a collection of only the matching elements when passed a collection of strings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Leaving aside what interface you should be testing for, the **sole problem** with your code is the **accidental use of the [automatic `$input` variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Automatic_Variables#input)**, which should never be used for custom purposes:

It is unfortunate that PowerShell doesn't *prevent* such custom use, which leads to subtle bugs, as in your case:

```bash
# !! The attempt use of $input as a custom *parameter variable*
# !! is preempted by the *built in* $input value, representing *pipeline input*
# !! -> 'Object[]'
 & { [CmdletBinding()] param([object] $input) $input.GetType().Name } 42
```

That is, the attempt to use `$Input` as a *parameter* (variable) was effectively *ignored*.

---

The ***customary* name for a non-type-constrained parameter** is **`$InputObject`** (though it is typically also declared with `[Parameter(ValueFromPipeline)]` to allow binding *via the pipeline*, which in your case wouldn't be useful).

The following function, `Test-Enumerability`:

- shows the use of an `$InputObject` parameter.
- follows PowerShell's naming conventions
- is an enhanced implementation that **indicates for a given object whether its use *in PowerShell's pipeline* would result in its enumeration**.

```bash
function Test-Enumerability {
  [CmdletBinding()]
  param (
    [Parameter(Mandatory)]
    [object] $InputObject
  )

  ($InputObject -is [System.Collections.IEnumerable] -and
    $InputObject -isnot [System.Collections.IDictionary] -and
    $InputObject -isnot [string] -and 
    $InputObject -isnot [System.Xml.XmlNode]
  ) -or
  $InputObject -is [System.Data.DataTable] -or
  $InputObject -is [System.Collections.IEnumerator]
  
}
```

Note:

- The logic has been gleaned from [PowerShell's source code](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/blob/48c7e112db8f0506a74555c83ecb8bec509b6597/src/System.Management.Automation/engine/LanguagePrimitives.cs#L523).
- There is a subtlety with respect to [`System.Collections.IDictionary`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Collections.IDictionary), i.e. with dictionary types such as [(ordered) hashtables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Hash_Tables):

  - As of PowerShell (Core) 7.3.x, instances of a type that *only* implements the *generic* version of that interface, [`` System.Collections.Generic.IDictionary`2 ``](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Collections.Generic.IDictionary-2), *are* enumerated - unexpectedly.
  - While most types that implement the latter *also* implement the former, there are some that don't: see [GitHub issue #15204](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/15204).

    - As an aside: The problem does *not* apply to the non-generic / generic [`System.Collections.IEnumerable`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Collections.IEnumerable) / [`` System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1 ``](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable-1) interface pair, because the latter *derives* from the former.

Comment: Bingo.  Thank you for addressing the root problem and for the useful notes and backround info!

Answer (score 1):

Your function's name has actually the interface you should be using for your comparison, [`ICollection`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.icollection?view=net-7.0):

```bash
function IsCollection {
    [CmdletBinding()]
    param (
        [Parameter( Mandatory = $true )]
        [object] $InputObject
    )

    $InputObject -is [System.Collections.ICollection]
}

IsCollection @{}    # true
IsCollection @()    # true
IsCollection string # false
```

If you want to include lists and arrays but exclude dictionary types, then change to [`IList`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.ilist?view=net-7.0):

```bash
function IsIList {
    [CmdletBinding()]
    param (
        [Parameter( Mandatory = $true )]
        [object] $InputObject
    )

    $InputObject -is [System.Collections.IList]
}

IsIList @{}    # false
IsIList @()    # true
IsIList string # false
```

Comment: While this doesn't address the root issue asked about, I appreciate you bringing up the nuances of which interface should ideally be looked for :-)